# Decide and prove whether the following functions are complex differentiable. If so, find their derivatives.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

a) f(z)=g($\bar{z}$)

Ok, so I am trying to show using Cauchy Riemann equation that this function is either complex differentiable or not. The only problem is I'm not 100% sure if I took the partials of $u_y$ and $v_y$ correctly. The mess below is my work.

g(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) $\ \ \ \ \ \ \  $f(z)=$\tilde{u}(x,y)+ i\tilde{v}(x,y)$

g($\bar{z}$)=u(x,-y)+iv(x,-y)

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[\tilde{u}(x,y)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[u(x,-y)]=u_x(x,-y)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[\tilde{u}(x,y)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[u(x,-y)]=u_y(x,-y)$ [or is it $-u_y(x,-y)$] <--- This is where I am confused

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[\tilde{v}(x,y)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[v(x,-y)]=v_x(x,-y)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[\tilde{v}(x,y)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[v(x,-y)]=v_y(x,-y)$ [or is it $-v_y(x,-y)$] <--- This is where I am confused

Then using Cauchy-Riemann equation we want to show if f(z) is analytic:

$\tilde{u}_x=\tilde{v}_y$ and $\tilde{u}_y=-\tilde{v}_x$

Any assistance would be excellent. If this question is confusing, then please message me.

Comment: You have to have some hypotheses on $f$ or $g$.  We don't even know whether any of the partial derivatives exist.  Are you asking something like "Is $g$ holomorphic if $f$ is holomorphic?

Comment: No, I'm trying to use the Cauchy Riemann equation to see if f(z) is complex differentiable. So I took the partial differentiable of f(z)=g($\bar{z}$). I'm just not sure if I took $u_y$ and $v_y$ correctly.

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule, the bracket versions of your derivatives are the correct ones. I assume that $g$ is supposed to be holomorphic wherever these computations take place, otherwise the problem would make little sense.

Therefore you see that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied if and only if the derivatives both vanish everywhere. As a rule of thumb, anything that involves $\bar{z}$ is most likely not going to be holomorphic (obviousy unless the bars can be cancelled in some way); it is as far as you can be from being holomorphic. Such functions as your $f$ are called anti-holomorphic for that reason.

Comment: Sorry, my professor didn't really explain what it meant for a function to be holomorphic. It was not noted on the homework, so I'm going to trust you.

Comment: As an (unexpected) exception to the rule of thumb, though, it happens that if $g(z)$ is holomorphic, then so is $\overline{g(\overline{z})}$.

Comment: Interesting to notice indeed. Holomorphic functions do inherit keep properties from polynomials in some ways :)

Comment: @Nixie777 holomorphic is just short (somewhat) for "complex differentiable".

Comment: @DanielSchepler How is it an exception to the rule?

Comment: Ohhh thank you @ArnaudMortier

Comment: @Nixie777 You're welcome :) what Daniel means is that the expression $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$  apparently involves lots of bars, yet produces a holomorphic function if $f$ was holomorphic.